# How to run tests in node.js with compoundjs

Tags: node.js, nodeunit, compoundjs

I am trying to figure out how to run tests in compound. When i run npm test I receive the following error.

```
describe('AccountController', function() {
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/test/controllers/accounts_controller.test.js:14:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at /Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/lib/nodeunit.js:75:37
at _concat (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:513:13)
at async.forEachSeries.iterate (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:123:13)
at async.forEachSeries (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:139:9)
at _concat (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:512:9)
at Object.doSeries [as concatSeries] (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:152:23)
at exports.runFiles (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/lib/nodeunit.js:73:15)
at _concat (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:518:13)
at async.forEach (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:110:25)
at _concat (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/deps/async.js:515:17)
at exports.modulePaths (/Users/sugarfist/WebstormProjects/nimbus/node_modules/nodeunit/lib/utils.js:65:24)
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I installed should, supertest and sinon, but i can not get past this error. I also tried installing jasmine and running that but I get 0 assertions...etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/). By default compound not using nodeunit since  version 1.1.5.

```
npm install mocha should
```

run tests

```
NODE_ENV=test mocha test/controllers/*
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing and it's now working with mocha test/*

Comment: Interesting enough, everything runs fine on my local machine, but when I run it on the Ubuntu server i get:  
 
 1) AccountController "before each" hook:
 Error: done() invoked with non-Error: [object Object]